# Kali 2.0 Linux doesn't start in GUI

Tags: kali-linux, gui, desktop-environment

I've had some trouble installing a dual-boot system on my laptop. I used Boot-Repair and now both systems (Windows 10 and Kali Linux 2.0) are showing up in Grub.

My problem is that, whenever I start Linux it just starts a terminal. I've tried to check if the desktop environment is still installed but I just get:

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Please post the exact command you're running

Comment: I tried to install gnome to display if its already installed: 1. apt-get install gnome-shell

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the installation of kali did not finish. You may be able to correct the problem by running `apt-get update` first, and then installing gnome-shell as you were trying; however, if the packages weren't installed properly, there's a good chance that many other things failed as well, leaving you with a badly functional system even if you can get this problem resolved.

I would suggest that, rather than trying to fix the broken installation, you just do the installation again.